# Is it possible to get the HWID on linux and windows in C# without WMI?

Tags: linux, hwid

*Hi :)* I'm writing a C# application and need to get the HWID code for the computer the code is running on. Since this is a console, i need to figure out a way to find the HWID for the CPU, motherboard and HDD, ***without*** using the the WMI. Since the system.management is not available on linux, i need it without using that. is it possible to find the HWID without the WMI? Or could i find a way to use the WMI for linux to find the HWID?

Is it possible in C# to do this? I would appreciate if anyone told me how, or pointed me in the right direction to get started. thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link, not sure if it will work on linux though.

**Updated**

```
private string GetUID()
{
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    Guid G = new Guid(); HidD_GetHidGuid(ref G);

    strB.Append(Convert.ToString(G));

    IntPtr lHWInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(123); HWProfile lProfile = new HWProfile();
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(lProfile, lHWInfoPtr, false);

    if (GetCurrentHwProfile(lHWInfoPtr))
    {
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(lHWInfoPtr, lProfile);
        strB.Append(lProfile.szHwProfileGuid.Trim(new char[] { '{', '}' }));
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lHWInfoPtr);

    SHA256CryptoServiceProvider SHA256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] B = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strB.ToString());

    string outStr = BitConverter.ToString(SHA256.ComputeHash(B)).Repla ce("-", null);

    for(int i = 0;i < 64; i++)
    {
        if (i % 16 == 0 && i != 0) 
            outStr = outStr.Insert(i, "-");
    } 

    return (outStr);
}

[DllImport("hid.dll")]
private static extern void HidD_GetHidGuid(ref Guid GUID);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetCurrentHwProfile(IntPtr fProfile);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class HWProfile
{
    public Int32 dwDockInfo;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 39)]
    public string szHwProfileGuid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szHwProfileName;
}
```

Comment: how do i use the api and structs though? that is kind of confusing, the rest makes sense.

Comment: It's in C#... I don't use linux, you asked for code that doesn't use WMI.

Comment: i was asking how to use the code under the part that says api, but fair enough, thanks for the response